# Can't access extension from init.db

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to create function that uses pgcrypto extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto SCHEMA public;

CREATE FUNCTION public.on_add_employee_account() RETURNS trigger AS
$add_employee_account$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT FROM public.employees WHERE emp_login = NEW.emp_login) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'User with such login already exists';
    end if;

    NEW.emp_pass = crypt(format('%s', NEW.emp_pass), gen_salt('md5'));
    RETURN NEW;
end ;

$add_employee_account$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_employee_account
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON public.employees
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.on_add_employee_account();
```

But when init.db is trying to insert values, it raises error:

ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist at character 50

No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

NEW.emp_pass = crypt(format('%s', NEW.emp_pass), gen_salt('md5'))

```
INSERT INTO public.employees
VALUES (1, 'Mike', 'Brown', '@mike', 'qwerty1234', '+77777777777', 'mikebr@gmail.com', 'MNDP');
```

Perhaps, it's running in single transaction and extension isn't created yet?

Answer (score 0):

You made the old mistake of not specifying the schema of the function, so you depend on the `search_path`. And thata parameter seemingly does not include `public` when you call the function.

Do the correct thing and

```
/* so that the schema is secure */
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

/* set "search_path" for the duration of the function call */
ALTER FUNCTION public.on_add_employee_account()
   SET search_path = public;
```